# how to install jdbc driver for sql server

Tags: sqljdbc

Hi I am new to  eclipse  ; I am trying to do example of nhibernate ; I downloaded sqljdbc4jar and uzipped it but when I double click to install it is not installing and no messages on windows 7 why it is not installing.however in windows 8 i am getting messages: cannot launch this type of file file types that contain executable code like exe ..cannot be launched

Comment: What kind of file did you download? If you have SQLJDBC.XXX already in you C drive then you should not do anything with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downloading JDBC driver for SQL Server from this Microsoft website:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774

This Binary Code is: Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server

Make sure you follow the installation instruction on the same link, to probably install it.

Comment: actually you do not need to 'install' just unzip and add to your app  from build path add external archive

Comment: made change but still ........................Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: JDBC Driver class not found: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerDr

Comment: @kobosh If you are have Eclipse IDE, then I guess you have MinGW compiler. You need to copy and paste JDBC driver ".EXE", jdbc.exe file to a folder where you installed Java thus under: C:Java/jdk1.7.0_15/bin. This is where the Java compiler looks for all of its executable files. Then if you have JDBC ".DLL" copy and paste Jdbc.dll file to C:Windows/System32. This is where all windows .dll files are located. I am assuming you are programming with Java and you are running a 32 bit computer system.

Comment: For some reason download does not work. No matter how many times I try to. Any alternative resource until Microsoft fixes it (if they do)?

Comment: On about the 10th attempt the download worked for me, and it started downloading the drivers about 10 times.